# format number with dash after first three and second four Jquery or Javascript

Tags: jquery

How do I check if a user has added a dash after first three numbers and second four and if the user did not add dash, format the number by adding dash after the first three numbers and the second four as the user is typing and append back to the input box.

PS: I have used Jquery Mask, does not work well on all browsers and also has bug issue on mobile

I also checked this post  https://codepen.io/SammyIsra/pen/bWgWZq did not answer my question

MY CODE:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Phone Number" id="number_here">

 User phone number input = XXXXXXXXXXX
```

WHAT I WANT IT TO BE

```
 XXX-XXXX-XXXX
```

format it by first checking dash after first three numbers and second four and if missing (WAS NOT ADDED BY THE USER) when typing, add it automatically from

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX to XXX-XXXX-XXXX
```

when user is typing and append back.

Comment: There are numerous mask plugins/scripts around that will do this for you

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your comment, but mask doesn't work well on mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link you provided had good solution, I don't understand how it did not answer your question.

It suggested to make sure to divide number while user was typing automatically...

Here is Vanilla JS solution with same tactic:

```js
document.querySelector("#number_here").addEventListener("keypress", (e) => e.target.value.length === 3 ? e.target.value = e.target.value + "-" : e.target.value.length === 8 ? e.target.value = e.target.value + "-" : null)
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Phone Number" id="number_here" value="">
```

When first 3 numbers are typed add `-` to value, do the same on mark 8...

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works, but when i try to clean the input it stop cleaning when i reach the "-" except i highlight the whole input and clear, it then works.

Comment: @Shasha You can simply use keypress event then. Check the fiddle now.